# Sqlalchemy WHERE clause doesn't filter children in tree structure

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi

I got tree model of Tag Categories with join_depth and Tags for each Tag Category:

```
class TagCategory(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tag_categories"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, index=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(index=True)
    organization_id: Mapped[Optional[int]] = mapped_column(
        ForeignKey("organizations.id")
    )
    parent_id: Mapped[Optional[int]] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("tag_categories.id"))
    role = Column(Enum(TagCategoryRoles))
    tags: Mapped[list["Tag"]] = relationship(
        back_populates="tag_category", cascade="all, delete-orphan", lazy="selectin"
    )
    children: Mapped[list["TagCategory"]] = relationship(
        "TagCategory",
        backref=backref("parent", remote_side=[id]),
        lazy="joined",
        join_depth=7,
    )


class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tags"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, index=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(index=True)
    disabled: Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(default=False)
    tag_category_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("tag_categories.id"))
    tag_category: Mapped["TagCategory"] = relationship(back_populates="tags")
```

Query works fine until I try to add where and filter result.

```
if name:
        where_clause.append(
            TagCategory.name.ilike(f"%{name}%") 
            | Tag.name.ilike(f"%{name}%")
        )
    if status is not None:
        where_clause.append(Tag.disabled == status)
    query = (
        select(TagCategory).where(TagCategory.parent_id.is_(None))
        .join(Tag, isouter=True)
        .where(*where_clause)
        .options(contains_eager(TagCategory.tags))
    )
```

It works only for the first level of TagCategory children and Tags in the first level and doesn't lookup deeper levels, so if I filter for some text that appears deeper, the query returns empty result. I guess that is because each level of the tree is a separate join and where works only for the first one, but I can't figure out how to filter in all the tree.